# Same variable value across nodeJS and Python files

Tags: python, node.js

I'm building a website using nodeJS and express. I also will have some functionality that requires me to run a Python script (using Python for its math / machine learning libraries). I was wondering is there a way my nodeJS files and Python files can reference one variable so that I only need to declare this variable once? (Kind of like the `res` directory, in an Android application, that holds xml files in which all Java files can reference).

Example: nodeJS and Python will need to use the same string value so I'd like them to reference the same one rather than declaring them independently in each file (to minimize mistakes etc..). Is the best way to store these values in a database? And does the answer also depend on if we are trying to keep this value as private as possible?

Comment: If you're running the Python script as part of some request in node.js, then you should just pass the value to the Python script when you start it.  If it's not a dynamic value that changes a lot, you can just put the value in a JSON file and have each script just read it from disk when needed.  For a single value, I wouldn't introduce a database just for that.  For data that doesn't need to persist, you can also use redis.

Comment: You can save the variables in the ENV variable of your system. Only if the variables is static. 
If its dynamic try writing it to a simple file in JSON for easy communication and then fetch it from your python script and use it